# Functors not recognized as transform_view args

Tags: c++, functor, std-ranges

In my mind I have this mental model of considering these two expressions being synonymous

```
R | std::views::transform([](auto&& e) { return f(e); });    
R | std::views::transform(f); // good, saves unnecessary lambda
```

However I've got a counter case [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bMzev6nzP)

```
#include <generator>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>

std::generator<int> to_prime_factors(int x) {
    for (int i = 2; i < x; ++i) {
        while (x % i == 0) {
            co_yield i;
            x /= i;
        }
    }

    if (x > 1) {
        co_yield x;
    }
}

template <std::ranges::input_range R>
std::map<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, int> to_counter(R&& range) {
    std::map<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, int> counter;
    for (auto&& ele : range) {
        counter[ele]++;
    }

    return counter;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(
        std::same_as<int, std::ranges::range_value_t<std::generator<int>>>);

    auto as = std::views::iota(2, 6);

    as | std::views::transform(to_prime_factors) |
        std::views::transform([](auto&& factors) {
            static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<decltype(factors)>);
            return to_counter(factors); // stinky unnecessary lambda
        });

    as | std::views::transform(to_prime_factors) |
        std::views::transform(to_counter); // oops

    return 0;
}
```

From GCC log it indicates that it fails to recognize the last expression as a partial adapter,
because of a mismatch in arity, yet it also indicates `Args = {}` which does not match my expectations as I have passed `to_counter`.

Questions:

- Why does wrapping a trivial-forwarding lambda gives different compilation resuts
- Why GCC ignored `to_counter` as an argument of `transform_view`?

Comment: You just linked to the main page of https://godbolt.org/, there's no code there. Please also paste the full code to the question itself.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat my bad, pasted the code & updated link now

Comment: You can also use `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` like: `std::views::transform(BOOST_HOF_LIFT(to_counter))`. Here is the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x1rra37G7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think that

```
[](auto&& e) { return f(e); }
```

is superfluous, but it is actually useful. It allows `f` to be not necessarily a functor, but many other things, including a set of overloaded functions, a function template, or a function from namespace std (which C++ standard prohibits using directly in place of a functor).

As a side note, to preserve the perfect forwarding intended by using the forwarding reference (`auto&&`), you should use `std::forward` in your lambda:

```
   [](auto&& e) { return f(std::forward<decltype(e)>(e)); }
```

Now returning to your source code.

While your question starts with "Functors not recognized ...", `to_counter` is not a functor, not even a function - it is a *function template*. You can replace your definition of `to_counter` with a real functor, i.e., with an object of type containing a generic `operator()` - then everything will compile:

```
inline struct {
    template <std::ranges::input_range R>
    std::map<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, int> operator()(R&& range) {
        std::map<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, int> counter;
        for (auto&& ele : range) {
            counter[ele]++;
        }

        return counter;
    }
} to_counter{};
```